# What is the theory that existence, life, and/or consciousness arise simply because all possibilities must be exhausted, and this is one of them?

Tags: metaphysics, existence, possible-worlds

I distinctly recall reading a Wikipedia page listing multiple theories on the origin of existence itself. One in particular, described in the title, was fascinating and came to mind recently, but I can't recall its name or find the page. I'd like to dig back into it - does anyone know the theory name or page?

Again, that theory of the origin of existence is that it arises simply because all possibilities must be exhausted and this is one of them.

I've tried digging around Wikipedia with no luck so far on these pages:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_physics
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_why_there_is_anything_at_all
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abiogenesis

Comment: Aha! Getting on the right track: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-tuned_Universe

Comment: Thanks for this question.  I've been leaning towards this viewpoint, philosophically and physically, and this led to a few new sources of interesting info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the web of Wikipedia pages referencing the theory I'm getting at:

- [Multiverse theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse#Anthropic_principle) as an explanation for the [fine-tuned universe proposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-tuned_Universe) (closely related to the [anthropic principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropic_principle#String_theory)).

Explained outside of Wikipedia, in [The Anthropic Principle:
is Fine Tuning of Nature due to
Multiverse and/or Intelligent Design?](http://www.asa3.org/ASA/education/origins/anthropic-cr.htm) by Craig Rusbult, Ph.D

> Scientists have analyzed the probability of a universe capable of supporting life-forms that are intelligent, and have estimated the odds to be extremely low.  If there is only one universe, and it was not designed for life, we must conclude that we are extremely lucky.  But if we live in a multiverse containing an immense number of universes, then (if the universes are numerous enough, and if their properties are distributed across a wide enough range so it's a diverse multiverse) the odds would favor having at least one universe with intelligent life.  Basically, a diverse multiverse provides a way to beat the odds and thus decrease the logical support for design-claims.

Answer (score 1):

Everett's [Many Worlds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation) interpretation of quantum dynamics takes this basic form.  It has been elaborated into the 'Multiverse theory', but this is not really any different.

Answer (score 1):

> Scientists have analyzed the probability of a universe capable of
>   supporting life-forms that are intelligent, and have estimated the
>   odds to be extremely low

If that is so, then I would try to figure out whether this universe we are living in is actually the original "creation" for a lack of a better word. If it's not, then scientists may be analyzing the wrong factors to come to this conclusion. Maybe in the original universe life develops "automatically" and consciousness may always be part of it.

I believe the multiverse-theory and a potential ancestor-simulation are both compatible. It's not impossible that the multi-verse is a result of a gigantic simulation to figure out an answer to your question.

However, I personally believe that an ancestor-simulation linked to actual beings/souls would serve as either a form of education or entertainment or both.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Philosophy.SE. You might want to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) and read through the [help center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help) in order to find out about the concept and needs of that site. One aspect of this that as hard as it might sound: Your own opinion does not count much as long as you cannot ground it in some kind of publicly accessible, external source. Your task would be building your answer on it by highlighting and commenting parts that are relevant for answering the question.